# Can't connect to my Samsung Note 9

Tags: android, 18.10, samsung

I can't connect to my Samsung Note 9. Does anyone know what's the problem and how to fix it?

[image: can't connect to Samsung Note 9]

Comment: when does this occur? do you ever get to see inside or does this happen as soon as you plug it in? have you turned on device sharing on your phone after pluging it in? https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Android-Phone-to-Computer#Using_Windows_sub

Comment: 2 months before, I plugin that to a windows , it is working fine , but not work on my Ubuntu, the sharing works on the Windows but not on Ubuntu, and also I allow the Ubuntu access to my phone, not work and appear the photo I upload above

Answer (score 0):

USB file transfer with Samsung Note 9 sort of works for me, but it takes ages and ages to transfer large files or large numbers of files...

There is a solution... It is a stand alone app on Linux. Read about it at the link below. I hope this helps.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/android-file-transfer-app-linux?fbclid=IwAR3Hts7EEa5iCQ5ccfR1xFYC1-kGYbu0WxAPA2GhT6TIfrfGLhNKOleWO3I

In Ubuntu 18.04 the file app will mount it immediately after pluuging the phone to the computer USB port. Click on the unmount icon next to the phone label that appears on the bar on the left, so only the label remains, then open this app. It works wonderfully when it is opened as the only mtp device app connected. You cannot view or run files from it, but file transfer is very speedy, indeed.